# log4net to exclude custom field name when its value is empty

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I want to exclude the custom field name when it's value is empty

my config file

```
 <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level Rules =%property{Rules} MethodName =%property{MethodName} %message%newline" />
```

My logger

```
log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["MethodName"] = method;
log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["Rules"] = Rules;
```

output:

> 2016-03-25 04:46:54,057 [9] INFO Rules = {"Rule1":"1"} MethodName
>   ="Method"

when there is are rules can we make the log to be like this

> 2016-03-25 04:46:54,057 [9] INFO  MethodName ="Method"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the only way to do this without custom code is to make the `Rules` property include the whole string, including it's caption: you only set the value if there are rules.

```
if (Rules.Any())
    log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["Rules"] = "Rules = " + Rules;
```

And config:

```
<conversionPattern value= "%date [%thread] %-5level %property{Rules} 
                           MethodName =%property{MethodName} %message%newline" />
```

Comment: I considered this option but we are also logging into the database. So, I would like to know whether we can do anything on XML side. Otherwise i should end up using another variable for database like "RulesToDb" and use "Rules" for File Appender and "RulesToDb" for ADO Appender .

Comment: Using two properties would be the simplest way. Log4net's default pattern layout class can't do this kind of conditional formatting.